# TYPO3 7.6.x Extbase Validation

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to validate my parameter with my own validator, but it's not called, but why?

```
/**
 * action create
 *
 * @param \Company\MyExt\Domain\Model\ProtokollKalender $newProtokollKalender
 * @validate $newProtokollKalender \Company\MyExt\Validation\Validators\KalenderValidator
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(\Company\MyExt\Domain\Model\ProtokollKalender $newProtokollKalender)
....
```

Comment: what not called? action or your validation, Please describe more so we can help.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? I find that old annotations die hard.

Comment: Please post code from validator file

Answer (score 0):

The annotation in PHPdoc to trigger the validator seems to be correect ([see documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html#interaction-of-validators)).

```
/**
 * @param Model $property
 * @validate $property \Vendor\Extension\Validation\Validator\CustomValidator
 */
public function someAction(Model $property) {}
```

Besides that, there is a shorter way to reference to validators in the sub-namespace `~\Validation\Validator`.

```
/**
 * @param Model $property
 * @validate $property Vendor.Extension:Custom
 */
public function someAction(Model $property) {}
```